# How to embed a self-signed certificate in the body of a PowerShell script?

Tags: azure, powershell, certificate, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

With the following command I am able to generate self-signed certificate at PowerShell prompt:

```
$mycert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "myhost.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Then I can export it to a PFX file:

```
$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force –AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath .\mycert.pfx -Password $mypwd -Cert $mycert
```

Finally, I can import the certificate into Azure Keyvault:

```
$kvcert = Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName mykeyvault  -Name mycert -FilePath .\mycert.pfx -Password $mypwd
```

The above commands work well for me and I can call `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate` repeatedly without any errors. Which is important for me, because I want to call the command from an Azure pipeline as a build for pull requests in our team.

My question is -

I don't want to commit the PFX file into our Git repo.

Instead I want to inline the base64 content of it in a PowerShell script, just to have 1 less file in the repo and not having to figure out URL and SAS token for the pipeline.

I am able to base64 format the PFX file content with the follwoing commands at the PowerShell:

```
$Bytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:\tmp\mycert.pfx");
$Base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes);
```

And now I could copy-paste it into my PowerShell script with `$Base64 = "D3AB.....ICB9A==";`

But how to pass it to the `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate` command in my script?

Is there some trick like `echo $Base64 | Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -FilePath -` like in Linux for STDIN?

Comment: Not tried it and it isn't very well documented, but does the [`-CertificateString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/import-azurekeyvaultcertificate?view=azurermps-6.13.0) parameter allow you to do this?

Comment: `-CertificateString` indeed expects a b64 string with the cert+key.

Comment: This works indeed! Sorry for missing that. Is there a way to embed large strings into Powershell scripts similar to Perl and PHP?

Comment: Point of note for future reference. echo is an alias for Write-Host. Write-Host should be generally avoided/not used (especially on the pipeline) except when outputting colorized screen text or another specific formatting use case. See these, by the father of Powershell Jeffry Snover -  [write host considered-harmful](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful)   ---  [With PowerShell v5 Write-Host...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Information?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: As for stdin/stdout stuff see the PowerShell help docs on the topic. [About Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7). As for embedding strings, yes. For example, you can convert a jpg to base64, even binary data and add that to your script. See [Embed binary data in your script](https://trevorsullivan.net/2012/07/24/powershell-embed-binary-data-in-your-script/)